# How can I process scheduled tasks effeciently?

Tags: c#, architecture

The application that I work on is 20+ years old. A lot of windows services are being used to handle scheduled tasks. For instance, if a payment is scheduled for processing, it is added into a queue, a database table, which contains all the information required to start the processing. A windows service then picks this up, changes the status on the queue to 'Processing' and starts the actual processing. In the event of an error, the status changes to 'Error' and if successful, sets the status to 'Completed'. While this worked well for sometime, it is now taking longer to process due to the increase in volume. We're also seeing deadlocks on the database tables as multiple instances of this service (deployed 3-4 instance for scale) are trying to read/update the same database table.

This application is not on the cloud so there's no cloud specific solution that can be used. Is there anyway the design/architecture can be changed, to use say RabbitMQ or something similar, to achieve this?

This application is built using ASP.NET MVC, C# and MSSQL.

Comment: If the database is a bottleneck, you could first look at your queries in the query analyzer. That will give you more information about why you would get deadlocks.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen We're already analyzing the database queries to check where it might cause a deadlock. That still fixes just one part of the problem. I'm looking at redesigning the entire scheduled tasks to make use of modern techniques

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize the queries by adding indexers or by sharding the database which will make you write less code but more work on the database side. But using messaging queues in such cases is always a better solution but requires good amount of effort.

Comment: can you point me to resources online as to how to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5318079/Sharded-Multi-Tenant-Database-using-SQL-Server-Row
As you have already mentioned RabbitMq, it's a better solution but the efforts will be more in terms of coding and redesigning.

Comment: I was actually looking for something to do with queues.